# Decoding attachments using Mail Gem and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rubygems, paperclip, email-attachments

I can receive emails via imap through the mail gem and would like to add the attachments to my model (called message). I receive this error based on my code taken from this [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/12/09/receiving-and-saving-incoming-email-images-and-attachments-with-paperclip-and-rails-3/):

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
```

My code:

```
mail.attachments.each_with_index do | attachment, index |
      fake_file = AttachmentFile.new("test.jpg")
      fake_file.write(attachment.decoded)
      fake_file.flush
      fake_file.original_filename = attachment.filename
      fake_file.content_type = "image/gif"

      @message.doc1 = fake_file if index == 0 and attachment.content_type.start_with?("image/")
end
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong to cause the error - maybe because the file is not read in binary mode? Another alternative was given in the same post:

```
file = StringIO.new(attachment.decoded)
      file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
      file.original_filename = attachment.filename
      file.content_type = attachment.mime_type
```

This worked once with a gif but failed with a pdf, providing rollbacks. Also, I am on Windows for Dev, which has lead to problems with paperclip in the past (file size not read properly etc.)

The model has the following validations:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :doc1, :content_type => [ 'application/pdf', /image/ ], :message => "only pdf or img"
```

My log files are not that helpful, only normal output for the first and second option:

```
 Command :: SET PATH=/usr/bin;%PATH% & file -b --mime "C:/Users/FOUNDA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20150412-5216-1utzh29.gif"
```

Not sure what kind of initialization there is for the mail gem - it is able to pull the emails correctly. Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your reply.

Comment: Please expand on your question a little. A stacktrace of where you get the error, along with how `mail` gets initialized would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by having a validation that requested a certain structure for the filename, which was causing problems. The second option I listed works flawlessly now. Can't speak for the first one - the problems there would be the same, probably.